# ID identity field value does not increase

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a form to bind id field as hidden value. But in controller, the id (key, auto identity increment) field always 0. Below is my code:

Model.cs

```
 public partial class A
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(255)]
    [Display(Name = "Institution Name")]
    [Required]
    public string InstitutionName { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Public")]
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool Category1 { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Private")]
    [DefaultValue(false)]


    [Display(Name = "Online")]
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool Category3 { get; set; }
    [
    [Display(Name = "Active?")]
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool active { get; set; }


    public A()
    {
        Category1 = false;
        Category2 = false;
        Category3 = false;
        active = true;

    }
}
```

Controller:

```
...
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "id,InstitutionName,Category1,Category2,Category3,active")] A A)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            db.A.Add(A);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(A);
    }
}
```

...

View - Create.cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

  <div class="form-horizontal">
      <h4>TransferSearch_revised</h4>
      <hr />
      @Html.HiddenFor(model=> model.id)
      @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
      <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InstitutionName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InstitutionName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InstitutionName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

...

The id value either 0 or empty. What's wrong with my code? Thanks.

Comment: Id value is 0 where ?

Comment: In the ActionResult Create() function when inserting into the database. When I move over db.savechanges(); the id field value is 0.

Comment: @user788448 before inserting the `id` will be zero because it's not created yet.

Comment: that is expected the  the id value will be auto generated when it saves the record.

Comment: if the id is 0 then savechanges() will generate error message like this: An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

Comment: I think you need to decorate the id property with `[Key]` as well. `[DatabaseGenerated]` is not enough.

Comment: if the expected id value is 0, then what does the error message mean? 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

Comment: forgot to mention my //get action for Create // GET: A/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            
           return View (new A());
           //   return View();
        }

Comment: I removed hidden id field in the view page and removed id column in the ActionResult Create() function and it finally works.